# Why find between brackets is matching wrong when I have more than one match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to find the text between two brackets and get them into array.

To do that, I use this regex: `/\{\{([^)]+)\}\}/`. (it matches the text between two brackets).

But when I have more than one match, it does the match wrong.

Why? it is because the regex is incorrect, or do I need to use some regex flag?

I was expecting to get an array of `foo` and `bar`.

```js
 const a = 'text:{{ foo }} {{bar}}';
const b = a.match(/\{\{([^)]+)\}\}/);
console.log(b);
```

My final goal is to transform this text: `text:{{ foo }} {{bar}}` to `'text:' + foo + bar`. this is mean I want to strip out the brackets and wrap the what is not brackets with a quote and contact them with a plus character.

To do that I want to find `foo` and `bar` and then split the text with the results and contact them.

Comment: It should be `^}` (instead of `^)`), and you can make your regex global using `/g` at the end to match multiple

Comment: If you just wannt the capture groups, you can use `.matchAll()` and access the second element from each array the iterator produces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had to do a task which required me to use a regex like yours to find and replace text between brackets, i wrote a one-liner function to do so and i'm posting it as an answer for future reference

```js
/**
 * @param str - The string to parse
 * @param conf - The object to get "variables" from (eg: { name: 'John' } would be the object if the string was 'Hello {{name}}')
 */
const parse = (str, conf) => str.replace(/{{(?<sc>[a-z]+)}}/g, (substr, match) => conf[match] ?? substr);
```

In your case you can use something like that:

```js
const a = 'text:{{ foo }} {{bar}}'
const b = a.match(/(?<=\{\{\s*)\w+(?=\s*\}\})/g)
console.log(b) // output: ['foo', 'bar']
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=\{\{\s*)`: this is a positive look-behind, it assert that the match is preceded by the regex between brackets, in this case i look for `{{` followed by 0 or more spaces
- `\w+`: matches any word character (`foo`, `bar`)
- `(?=\s*\}\})`: this does the same as the first group but it assert that the match is **followed** by the match between brackets, in this case i look for 0 or more spaces and then `}}`
- `g`: is the global modifier, i added it since i want to match all occurences of this regex and not stop after the first match

Comment: @Ivar you're right, i removed types but kept jsdocs for clarity